# How can I change the caption of a Listing which is outside of minted code?

Tags: listings, minted

I am working on a LaTeX document using the `scrarticle` class and the `minted` package for syntax highlighting. My objective is to have a properly aligned caption with the code listing, similar to the second image linked below. However, my current setup leads to a misaligned caption as shown in the first image.

This is my environment setting:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrarticle}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{breaklines, framesep=2mm, fontsize=\footnotesize, numbersep=5pt}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{python}
# Python code here
\end{minted}
\caption{Beispiel - SuperCode}
\label{listing:supercode}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

What I get is:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

I attempted to use the `listings` package to address this, but it caused an error and the `minted` environment within the listing was ignored.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use the `a4wide` package, it has not been updated size 1994! Use the `a4paper` class option instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find examples for changing the caption name in the section "Customizing the listing environment" of the [`minted` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/minted.pdf/0):

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrarticle}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{breaklines, framesep=2mm, fontsize=\footnotesize, numbersep=5pt}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Auflistung}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{python}
# Python code here
\end{minted}
\caption{Beispiel - SuperCode}
\label{listing:supercode}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]